# Sort array by trailing letters

Tags: php

I have an array like so (generated from an API):

```php
    [18] => 3107SkincareL
    [19] => 3INAL
    [20] => 3M
    [21] => 3rdRockEssentialsFL
    [22] => 4BeautyGroupL
    [23] => 4EVERMAGICCOSMETICSL
```

As you can see, some of the entries feature a trailing "L" or "FL".
I would like to sort everything ending with "L" into a group and everything that ends with "FL" into a group and everything else in another group.

Is there any possible way to do this in PHP?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `Is there any possible way to do this in PHP?` yes, of course

Comment: I would even say there are many possible ways to do this in PHP. If you actually try something you might find so too..

Comment: I'm teaching for more than two hours now and couldn't find something appropriate, that's why I'm asking

Comment: Yes, we are all busy. If you haven't got the time, then just don't do it.

Comment: I got the time, I just don't seem to find anything. Just a keyword for what to look for would help me out.

Comment: Well, the way, to see what the end of a string looks like, is with [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php). So, for instance, `substr($str, 0, -2) == "FL"`. And you need to loop to loop through the array. You could use [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). That's two keywords.

Comment: One of the simpliest way would be to separate in 3 differents arrays the parts ending with `L`, `FL` and other. Then, sort each arrays, and merge them

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps and I really don't know how I couldn't come up with this idea.

Comment: Because hard trying for 2 hours can be sterile. Take a break, take some air, try one of those skin cares or cosmetics from the array (huhu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$input = [
  18 => "3107SkincareL", 
  19 => "3INAL", 
  20 => "3M", 
  21 => "3rdRockEssentialsFL", 
  22 => "4BeautyGroupL", 
  23 => "4EVERMAGICCOSMETICSL", 
];
$output = [];
array_walk($input, function($entry) use (&$output) {
    if ("FL" == substr($entry, -2)) {
        $output["FL"][] = $entry;
    } else if ("L" == substr($entry, -1)) {
        $output["L"][] = $entry;
    } else {
        $output["?"][] = $entry;        
    }
});
print_r($output);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [L] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3107SkincareL
            [1] => 3INAL
            [2] => 4BeautyGroupL
            [3] => 4EVERMAGICCOSMETICSL
        )
    [FL] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3rdRockEssentialsFL
        )
    [?] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3M
        )
)
```